# Volume Integrals

Tags: geometry, integration

I encountered this problem in Griffiths' *Introduction to Electrodynamics*. The first problem under volume integrals (Example 1.8). It reads:

> Calculate the volume integral of $T = xyz^2$ over the prism in Fig. 1.24.
>   [image]

I understand how to perform integrals, but in this particular one I get lost while going through the solution provided. It's as if a step is jumped. The integral performed along $x$ confuses me since it has limits of $0$ and $(1 -y)$. How does $y$ not appear in the answer? It's as if some nicety is performed. I hope someone has come across the question in Griffiths before (and maybe even has the book at hand)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How does $y$ not appear in the answer?

Because you are integrating $y$ over the range 0 to 1:
$$
\int_0^1\left(y\int_0^{1-y}dx\,x\right)dy = \int_0^1\,y\cdot\frac12\left(1-y\right)^2dy=\left.\frac12\left(\frac13y^3-y^2+y\right)\right|_0^1=\frac16
$$

The reason you integrate $x$ from 0 to $1-y$ in the first place is because the maximum $x$ depends on your $y$ position. If $y=0$, then the maximum $x$ you have is 1; if $y=1$, then the maximum $x$ you have is 0; any $y$ in between has a linear relation with $x$.